# Get selected row id from table MVC

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to MVC and facing problem in getting selected index of table in AJAX post.

I have following class

```
 public class ContractModel
{
    public long HotelId { get; set; }
    public long RateCodeId { get; set; }
    public string RateCode { get; set; }
    public string HotelName { get; set; }
    public List<RateBandModel> RateBands { get; set; }
}

public class RateBandModel
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public DateBandModel Applicable { get; set; }
    public DateBandModel Bookable { get; set; }
    public string RoomType { get; set; }
    public long RoomTypeId { get; set; }
}
```

And here is my partial view

```
@model Packages.Website.Models.ContractModel

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SelectRateBand", "Contract", new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "product-table" }))
{       
  <input type="hidden" id="rowId" name="rowId" />
  <table border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="product-table">
    <tr>
        <th class="table-header-repeat line-left"><a href="">Room Type</a>  </th>
        <th class="table-header-repeat line-left"><a href="">Board Basis</a></th>
        <th class="table-header-repeat line-left"><a href="">From Date</a></th>
        <th class="table-header-repeat line-left"><a href="">To Date</a></th>
        <th class="table-header-repeat line-left"><a href="">Book From</a></th>
        <th class="table-header-repeat line-left"><a href="">Book To</a></th>
        <th class="table-header-options line-left"><a href="">Options</a></th>
    </tr>
    @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => Model.HotelId)
    @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => Model.RateCodeId)
    @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => Model.RateBands)
    @foreach (var item in Model.RateBands)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.Id)
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RoomType)
            </td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BoardBasis)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Applicable.FromDate)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Applicable.ToDate) </td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Bookable.FromDate) </td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Bookable.ToDate) </td>
            <td class="options-width">
                <input type="submit"  name="command" class="form-submit" />

            </td>
        </tr>
    }
  </table>
}
```

In Controller

```
   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SelectRateBand(ContractModel contract)
    {
        //Some code here

    }
```

Now in controller I get Contract.DateBands NULL
And I have no Idea how to get selected index please help me

Comment: What I generally do is to create a ViewModel of just the fields that I'm looking to capture.  If I'm reading this right, it looks like you are just after the RateBand.  So have your controller post accept a RateBand instead of a ContractModel.  Also, you'll either need a form for each row or preferably an Ajax post similar to what you have commented out.  This way you know which item you've selected.

Comment: It looks like the code you have is going to perform a form.submit, sending all of the rows back (and really since you only have a hiddenFor with the Id it's going to send all the IDs back). What exactly are you trying to do on the button click, send the single Id to the controller? Is your real problem tied to the ActionLink which you have commented out?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for reply. Actually I want only Rateband not ContractModel. What I want is on select click I should get selected rateband in controller

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? Your generating the properties for `RateBands` in a `foreach` loop so the input for property `RateBandModel.ID` is not named correctly and cant be bound to the model. You have multiple submit buttons for a single form (what are they supposed to do?) and you ajax call replaces the whole table. Perhaps explain what your trying to do so we can fix this code.

Answer (score 3):

If you are after the Id of the selected row, you can pass it as a route value with your Actionlink helper. I find using the named parameters convey your purpose more.

```
@Html.ActionLink(linkText: "Edit",
                 actionName: "SelectRateBand", 
                 controllerName: "YourController", 
                 routeValues: new { id = item.Id }, 
                 htmlAttributes: new { @class = "icon-1 info-tooltip", @Title = "Edit" });
```

And in your controller, change the action to accept an id parameter to match the id sent from the ActionLink.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SelectRateBand(string id)
{
    //Some code here

}
```

Comment: Hi Josh, I removed action link because I want to make ajax call to controller and I want to access selected rateband in controller.

Comment: Well once you pass the id back to the controller, you can look up whatever you need with that.